# How to check for string inequality using LLVM's FileCheck in the presence of CHECK-DAGs?

Tags: regex, llvm

I'm using [LLVM's FileCheck](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/FileCheck.html) to verify the results of some LLVM pass I've written.

I know I can check that two strings are equal by doing something like:

```
CHECK: first string = [[ID:[0-9]+]]
CHECK: second string = [[ID]]
```

But is there a way to check they are *not* equal? e.g., something like:

```
CHECK: first string = [[ID:[0-9]+]]
CHECK: second string = [[!ID]]
```

Of course `CHECK-NOT` is the obvious answer, however I'm actually using **`CHECK-DAG`** which doesn't play well with `CHECK-NOT`:

```
CHECK-DAG: this can appear anywhere
CHECK-DAG: first string = [[ID:[0-9]+]]
CHECK-DAG: second string = [[!ID]]
```

I'm specifically dealing with numbers here, so I'll be satisfied with a solution that only addresses that. If all else fails, even a solution that addresses just `[0-9]` (no repetition) will do.